# Vue.js. How to shift main content when opening a fixed sidebar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the ready-made sidebar from the page. [On this page](https://yaminncco.github.io/vue-sidebar-menu/#/props), when opening / closing, the main content is shifted to the right / left, while the sidebar has a `position: fixed` attribute. How do I make the same implementation of shifting content? Do I have to use `js`? Tried it - keeping track of the width of a given component and adding `marginLeft` to the main content when it changes. Perhaps there is a more elegant way.

```
  <sidebar-menu collapsed theme="white-theme" :menu="menu" />
  
  <div id="main-content">
      <vue-navbar></vue-navbar>

      <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <router-view">
            </router-view>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <vue-footer></vue-footer>


  </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: Need to shift main_content when sidebar-menu is open

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is keep track if the bar is collapsed or not. If is collapsed you apply some css class to shift the content to the right:

```
  <sidebar-menu :collapsed="collapsed" theme="white-theme" :menu="menu" />
  
  <div id="main-content">
      <vue-navbar></vue-navbar>

      <!-- adjust 'ml-10' to your needs -->
      <div :class="collapsed ? '' : 'ml-10'" class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <router-view">
            </router-view>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <vue-footer></vue-footer>


  </div>

<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      collapsed: true,
    }
  }
}

</script>
```